# Java swing JSplit - JList / JTabbedPane compatibility

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm working with Intellij IDEA, `Java 9.0.1` and `Gradle`.

I have a `JSplit` with a `JList` on the left and `JTabbedPane` on the right

[Picture for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKtH.jpg)

After creating some "open" function to import a text file to the program, I want to see the imported file in the following manner:

1. The filename.extension on the `JList` (LEFT)
2. The textual content on the `JTabbedPane` (RIGHT)

Considering I have a JMenuItem called Open with an action listener that when clicked should open a JFileChooser dialog - **after the user selected for say a text file, how can it be imported to both the JList and the JTabbedPane?**

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ListModel` to add the the file selections dynamically,
**Example:**

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> fileList = new JList<>(model);
```

**From your pictorial representation,**
1. Assuming you have a `JMenuItem` in the `JMenu`, you can add `ActionListener` for the menu item through which you can include your new file,

```
//add your JFileChooser and select the file
model.addElement("<your-file-name>");
//<Include-tabs-as-u-wish>
```

2. Include a `ListSelectionListener` which makes you move to the selected tab, where you can set the tab based on your fileName,

```
fileList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                String selectedFile=fileList.getSelectedValue();
                //make use of setSelectedIndex or setSelectedComponent in JTabbedPane
                //and focus the right tab
            }
        });
```

> **Note:** The `EventListener` gets changed based on the components you use on the JMenu

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since I'm having difficulties implementing this to my code (being my fault because I'm new), let me ask you this: I have a `JMenu` > `JMenuItem` called "Open" > I plan on adding something like a `JFileChooser`. When the user selects his file, I want the file to be added to the split pane (both `JList` and `JTabbedPane`). Does this extended information point you more to the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: I guess the above answer itself covers more about what you have asked for. But to add on, you can add your `JFileChooser` in the `ActionListener` mentioned in point 1.

Comment: What can I add to the `JFileChooser` that it will upload the file to both of the views accordingly though?

Comment: Well, Please try with the suggestions provided so far and come up by editing your question again with the things you have tried.